# How to invoke a function on every redirect using react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, https, react-router

I want to check for cookies every time a user gets redirected to a different Route. What would be the most conventional way to do this besides coding the function each time at the top of the main component which each Route loads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `useLocation` and the `useEffect` hook:

```
function App() {
  let location = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    //do your stuff
  }, [location]);

  return (
    // ...
  );
}
```

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you so much!